# JQuery script not working in Data table pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pagination

I have a **datatable** with **pagination** of 15 rows(10 rows in one page and remaining are in second page) . first 10 rows scripting is working. but when i click on the button 2 script is not working.

here is my code for edit the row cells based on their class names:

```js
$('.consignment').editable( function( sValue ) {
                               var aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition( this );
                               var aData = oTable.fnGetData( aPos[0] );
                               aData[ aPos[1] ] = sValue;
                               consignmentid1 = sValue;
                               //alert("consignmentid1"+consignmentid1);
                               //alert("hi");
                               return sValue;
                              }, { "onblur": 'submit' } ); 
                              oTable = $('#example').dataTable();
                              $('.actualprice').editable( function( sValue1 ) {
                               var aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition( this );
                               var aData = oTable.fnGetData( aPos[0] );
                               aData[ aPos[1] ] = sValue1;
                               actualprice = sValue1;
                               //alert("actualprice"+actualprice);
                               return sValue1;
                              }, { "onblur": 'submit' } ); 
                              oTable = $('#example').dataTable();
                              $('.actualweight').editable( function( sValue2 ) {
                               var aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition( this );
                               var aData = oTable.fnGetData( aPos[0] );
                               aData[ aPos[1] ] = sValue2;
                               actualweight = sValue2;
                               //alert("actualweight"+actualweight);
                               return sValue2;
                              }, { "onblur": 'submit' } );
                              oTable = $('#example').dataTable();
                              $('.actuallength').editable( function( sValue3 ) {
                               var aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition( this );
                               var aData = oTable.fnGetData( aPos[0] );
                               aData[ aPos[1] ] = sValue3;
                               actuallength = sValue3;
                               //alert("actualprice"+actualprice);
                               return sValue3;
                              }, { "onblur": 'submit' } ); 
                              oTable = $('#example').dataTable();
                              $('.actualwidth').editable( function( sValue4 ) {
                               var aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition( this );
                               var aData = oTable.fnGetData( aPos[0] );
                               aData[ aPos[1] ] = sValue4;
                               actualwidth = sValue4;
                               //alert("actualprice"+actualprice);
                               return sValue4;
                              }, { "onblur": 'submit' } ); 
                              oTable = $('#example').dataTable();
                              $('.actualheight').editable( function( sValue5 ) {
                               var aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition( this );
                               var aData = oTable.fnGetData( aPos[0] );
                               aData[ aPos[1] ] = sValue5;
                               actualheight = sValue5;
                               //alert("actualprice"+actualprice);
                               return sValue5;
                              }, { "onblur": 'submit' } ); 
                              oTable = $('#example').dataTable();
         
Add Comment Collapse
```

This code will edit 5 cells in a row based on class names.

Comment: "message": "SyntaxError: missing ; before statement", "lineno": 69

Comment: Hello @Hazonko, Thanks for your quick response. its not my complete code. forgot about code, My main problem is about query not working in pagination.